# Ubuntu 14.04 route timeout

Tags: linux, routes

I added a static route in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

`up route add -net 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 192.168.0.12`

But at night the Gateway 192.168.0.12 is shutdown for 2 hours (backup). Now every morning I must delete the route and add it again because the route falls on timeout. How can I deactivate the timeout for this route?

Comment: try to ask it on [Unix & Linux community](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Use schedule tasks in Linux to remove the route, flush route cache and restore the route everyday at 2AM (for example)?

Your file script.sh should be something like :

```
ip route del 10.0.0.1/31 via 192.168.0.12
ip route flush cache
ip route add 10.0.0.1/31 via 192.168.0.12
/etc/init.d/network restart 
#Maybe restarting network without removing and adding the route is enough.
```

Allow access to your file :

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

CronTab is the schedule task manager :

```
crontab -e
```

Add a line for your script :

```
* 2 * * * /[your_shell_script_path]/script.sh
```

Where asterisks are minute, hour, day of the month, month, day of the week.
So here the script will be executed each day at 2AM.

Hope this will help.